# Downloading raster from Natural Earth world raster directly into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, natural-earth

The world raster of Natural Earth can be downloading from their [website](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/).
Is their a way to download them directly into QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a a plugin that was made for this purpose[image]
Once you have this plugin it will appear in the Raster tool bar[image]

In the plugin window you will be able to choose the raster you want to download [image]

This raster is are heavy, up to 667 MB, so it will take few mints to download it[image]